# How does Amanda Waller watch the Suicide Squad?

Tags: dc, technology, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad, suicide-squad-2016

In *Suicide Squad*, there are several scenes where Amanda Waller is seen viewing the Squad through some sort of infrared video feed.

Is it explained where that feed is coming from? Is Waller hacking into cameras that were already there, or does she control her own cameras? If so, what happened to them later in the film?

Comment: If she's controlling her own cameras, I'd like to ask when exactly she had both the time and the motivation to set them up.  Before Enchantress escaped she had the former but not the latter, and after she had the latter but not the former.

Comment: @Kevin Or she's using cameras attached to drones, which wouldn't need to be set up prior to being required at all.

Comment: Take off their hats! No, wait, that’s popes in a Volkswagen.

Comment: Wasn't there a bit where she was asking for surveillance data on Team Bravo? For some reason, I want to say they specifically mentioned drones.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it explained where that feed is coming from?

Not really. This is a common movie [trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SinisterSurveillance). The government has eyes everywhere. It's never really explicitly stated whether the feed comes from drones, street surveillance cameras, satellite images, or some combination of these things (as is common with this sort of trope).

That being said, we can assume the military had different communication facilities set up because:

> **there is a scene where once Enchantress gets a hold of Amanda Waller, she uses Amanda's military knowledge to knock out strategic locations that presumably control these surveillance methods.**